# Google Play billing no action when trial ends

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing, google-play-console, play-billing-library

I'm using google play billing library 4.0.0 for subscription. With my old app everything is ok.

But with new app I have a problem - 80% of active trials do not convert to the paid version after 3 days (it's a trial period). They are not canceled or not in pending status, no error. They are still active in google console and nothing is happening.

First I thought about a grace period and I set it to none and nothing changed.

I would be grateful if you could tell me what could be the problem.

Comment: More information is needed to answer this question. What code are you using in your old vs new app? Are you using exactly the same version of the library? Have you [configured](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#products) both apps and their products in the same way?

Comment: Yea, I use the same library version for both app. I just found out that the problem is only with one 3 months sub (I have 2 subs with trial, 12 and 3 months, 12 months works)
So maybe the problem in this sub, but this 2 subs are identical except the price and period.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Thanks